# windows batch scripting: catch user reaction to "timeout" command

Tags: batch-file, timeout

I know that by using the "timeout" command, I can wait for specified amount of time; but my question is that what if this would be an automatic operation that could be prevented by user? I mean suppose that I wanted to do the operation A but by using the "timeout" command I wait if user wants to cancel this operation or not; for example during this waiting process if user pressed the Enter key then batch script execute something else(not operation A);[image]

Comment: time out is not the best choice here.Check `CHOICE` command help (there's even better option with `XCOPY` but will take me time to create a script)

Comment: I need that timer; it acts like a timed notification whether to do its automatic option or another option

Comment: in `choice` you have a timeout...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`timeout` is just to induce a delay before an action, not to let the user choose something. I f you still want to use it, you need to ask the user to press Control-C to break before the timeout command, and catch the ERRORLEVEL after that.

Else `choice` is your friend here:

```
C:\Users\mm>CHOICE /T 10 /C yYcC /CS /D y  /M "Press y to validate, c to Cancel. You have 10 sec delay [Default y]:"
Press y to validate, c to Cancel. You have 10 sec delay [Default y]: [y,Y,c,C]?y
```

And you can test returned value with ERRORLEVEL. Here, I pressed nothing, so y get selected (default value via /D) and ERRORLEVEL is 1 (1st option). The countdown is not displayed though.

[choice.exe reference at ss64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html)

Comment: Timeout let you press any key, which choice doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

As indicated by Aacini, no, timeout has been built without this feature.

This can be used as a workaround

```
@echo off

    call :controlTimeout 5
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo timeout was cancelled
    ) else (
        echo timeout reached
    )

    exit /b 

:controlTimeout 
    setlocal
    start "" /belownormal /b cmd /q /d /c "timeout.exe %~1 /nobreak > nul"
    timeout.exe %~1 & tasklist | find "timeout" >nul 
    if errorlevel 1 ( set "exitCode=0" ) else ( 
        set "exitCode=1"
        taskkill /f /im timeout.exe 2>nul >nul
    )
    endlocal & exit /b %exitCode%
```

This just starts two instances of timeout, one in background that is only cancelable with Ctrl+C and one in the active console. When the timeout command in console finished, tasklist is used to determine if the background timeout task is still active. If it is, then the visible timeout has been canceled, else timeout has been reached.

Answer (score 1):

Wow! I always thought that this capability was inherent to `timeout`, but it is not! There is no way to know if `timeout` command ends because the time out or because a key press...

However, it *is* possible to know if the time out was cancelled by Ctrl-C, instead by a normal key! In this case, the `errorlevel` value returned by `timeout` is different than zero:

```
C:\> timeout 60

Waiting for 47^Ceconds, press a key to continue ...
C:\> echo %errorlevel%
-1073741510
```

*However*, if you use this command inside a Batch file, the Ctrl-C press also cancel its execution! So the answer is: NO, there is no way to detect this point... **`:-(`**

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion with @jeb on @pologug's answer I finally came up with the following one-liner:

```
timeout -t 4 |findstr "\<0\>" >nul && echo timedOut || echo cancelled
```

Timeout uses control characters to relocate the cursor to the remaining seconds to rewrite them. Polo's and Jeb's answers employ a `for` loop to capture the seconds. This captured string contains the control characters and the string has to be postprocessed to be useful.

My answer uses `findstr` to search for `0` by word boundaries (making sure `10` or `204` aren't found). Thankfully, `findstr` treats control characters as "non-word-characters"

Instead of `echo` you can simply use `goto` to jump to different parts of the code.

Same downside as Jeb's answer though: the timeout-prompt isn't displayed (due to the piping).

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off & setlocal

set cnt=4

for /f tokens^=3^ delims^=^. %%i in ('timeout -t %cnt%^|find "."') do (
   echo %%i
)

pause
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post. Also take a peek at the [guide on formatting your posts using Markdown](/help/formatting) which renders the code well-formatted.

Comment: doesn't (even try to) answer the question.

Comment: @Stephan: It is an answer and it solves the problem, but it is over complicated and without explanation you have to discover the results on your own (just done)

Comment: @jeb: well, I might be blind today (I know you, so I doubt you're wrong), so please tell me, how does it execute something on pressing a key and something else when letting the timeout run out (or what to add to make it work).

Comment: @Stephan: If you don't press a key the output is `0`, else it outputs the remaining time in seconds. But if you press directly, then the output is empty. It could be much better, without the carets and probably without the find. Another drawback of the solution, it doesn't show the down counting value, because it has to be grabbed by the FOR-loop. But impressive, that there is a solution with timeout after 9 years

Comment: @jeb: ok, there is a number on the screen. But it's difficult (I found a way - a really awkward one) to capture it and reformat it to be usable in an `if` statement.

Comment: @Stephan: I added an answer with a full working sample

Comment: @jeb: that's what I meant when I said "awkward"... `:D`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76161212/463115) from @polo gug:

```
@echo  off

set cnt=9

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=# " %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  set "BS=%%a"
)

for /f "tokens=*" %%1 in ('timeout -t %cnt%') do (
   set "line=%%1"
)

set remain=%line:~-2%

if "%remain%" == " 0" goto :timeout    %= This is true for timeouts longer than 9 seconds =%
if "%remain%" == "%BS%0" goto :timeout %= This is true for timeouts shorter than 10 secondes
echo Canceled by user
exit /b

:timeout
echo Timeout occured
```

It grabs the output from the timeout command, then it inspects the last two characters.

If the remaining string is `<space>0` or `<backspace>0` then a timeout occured, else the user has canceled the timeout before.
Only test the last character against `0` isn't enough, because the remaining text could be ex. `20`.

Comment: I came up with another solution. Turned out the fix for the `for` loop doesn't even need the loop anymore.