# How to show progress in a batch file using sqlcmd?

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, cmd, database-backups, sqlcmd

I'm doing a backup of a large database in a dos batch file (not powershell), using sqlcmd ([sqlcmd reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)). It takes about 30 minutes.

```
sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 -d DbNameHere -E -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [DbNameHere] TO DISK = N'c:\Temp\MyBackup.bak' WITH COPY_ONLY, NOFORMAT, INIT, NAME = N'My Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10"
```

If you run the BACKUP command in SQL Management Studio, you get the output, as it happens:

```
10 percent processed.
20 percent processed.
...
```

In a DOS batch, at best, I get all the 10,20,30..100 all appearing on the screen at once, when the backup is finished.

I've tried playing with these parameters, but I still don't get the desired progress update on screen:

```
-m-1
-V 1
-r1
```

These progress messages are buffered, and that might be part of the problem. This is dicsussed here for example: [How do I flush the PRINT buffer in TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306945/how-do-i-flush-the-print-buffer-in-tsql)
But I have a single long running command, not multiple commands.

You can run a separate SQL statement elsewhere, and that tells you the progress and even the estimated finished time:

```
SELECT session_id as SPID, command, a.text AS Query, start_time, percent_complete, dateadd(second,estimated_completion_time/1000, getdate()) as estimated_completion_time 
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) a 
WHERE r.command in ('BACKUP DATABASE','RESTORE DATABASE')
```

But to use that, I would have to create a second batch file (with a sqlcmd executing this statement), make it open in a new window just before running sqlcmd backup, and run it in a loop on a 1 minute timer maybe, and end it when the backup is finished. All that in batch. Ideally, I'd rather keep it all in a single batch file! Outputting the standard progress messages would be much simpler!

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it show the progress immediately if you type the commands interactively after running `sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1`?

Comment: wOxxOm, if I run interractively `sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1`, after `1>` I type the backup command, after `2>` I type `GO` then `[return]`, the progress is not shown as it happens, it is all displayed in one go after completion of the whole backup statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come up with a sort of solution. Downside is that it involves a second batchfile. It basically launches a progress window with a given name. This progress window refreshes regularly. Once the main process is finished, it calls `taskkill` using the given name. The progress batch relies on `timeout`. Both are on my Windows 8 workstation and 2008 R2 and 2012 servers.

Main backup batch:

```
@echo off
rem lots of other lines in my main batch file here

start "BACKUP_PROGRESS" /belownormal cmd /d /c "backup_progress2.cmd"

sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 -d DBNameHere-E -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [DBNameHere] TO DISK = N'c:\Temp\DBNameHere.bak' WITH COPY_ONLY, NOFORMAT, INIT, NAME = N'DBNameHere-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10"

taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq BACKUP_PROGRESS" /F > nul

rem my main batch file continues here with lots of other lines
```

Progress batch file (called `backup_progress2.cmd` in the main batch).  The `setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion` is just so that I can display the time with seconds using `!time!`.

```
@echo off
rem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434982/windows-batch-scripting-catch-user-reaction-to-timeout-command
SET timeout=60

:loop
cls
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
echo.
echo Time now: !time!
echo.
endlocal
sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 -d DBNameHere -E -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON;SELECT start_time,cast(percent_complete as int) as progress,dateadd(second,estimated_completion_time/1000, getdate()) as estimated_completion_time, cast(estimated_completion_time/1000/60 as int) as minutes_left FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r WHERE r.command='BACKUP DATABASE'"
echo.
echo Refreshing every %timeout% seconds.
timeout %timeout% > nul
goto loop
```