# WAITFOR DELAY and PRINT statement

Tags: sql-server, while-loop, sleep

I have a simple while loop:

```
DECLARE @Counter INT 

SET @Counter = 1

WHILE (@Counter <= 10)

BEGIN

    PRINT 'The counter value is = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Counter) WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
    SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1
    
END
```

I expect that @counter value will be printed out with 1 second delay, but instead, code is executed after 10 seconds and result is printed at the end of the execution in one go.

```
The counter value is = 1
The counter value is = 2
The counter value is = 3
The counter value is = 4
The counter value is = 5
The counter value is = 6
The counter value is = 7
The counter value is = 8
The counter value is = 9
The counter value is = 10
```

How to make sure that every next value is printed out with 1 second delay, so I can monitor progress?

Just some backgroud. I would like to use similar script to monitor backup and restore progress.
E.g. assign initial value of progress percentage to:

```
SELECT @Counter = percent_complete
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r 
   CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) a 
WHERE r.command in ('BACKUP DATABASE','RESTORE DATABASE');
```

and monitor progress in while loop every 5 seconds till percent_complete reaches 100%.

Comment: _"How to make sure that every next value is printed out with 1 second delay, so I can monitor progress?"_ - **you can't**: Instead [you should use `RAISERROR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql) (sic) with `NOWAIT` instead of `WAITFOR` - that way your client will get the status messages instantly. Also, `WAITFOR` is a separate statement entirely, rather than a modifier for `PRINT`.

Comment: _"Just some backgroud. I would like to use similar script to monitor backup and restore progress. E.g. assign initial value of progress percentage to:"_ - this is not the best approach (imo) for passing backup/restore progress information to a TDS client: [consider using XEvents instead](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/new-extended-events-for-database-recovery-progress/ba-p/384452).

Comment: You can't report *backup* progress like this. The actual progress is already sent to the console anyway. I'd suggest using Ola Hallengren's [backup and restore scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) instead of rolling your own anyway. The scripts handle multiple databases and logging operations to a table. If you check the scripts you'll see that `SELECT` is used instead of `PRINT` to return results to the caller immediately.

Comment: @Dai Could just use `WITH STATS = 1` and pick it up off the Messages

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the advice already in the comments, try this modified script to demo how you can use *raiserror* for the behaviour you are expecting in your example code.

Remember to select the *Messages* table to view output.

```
declare @Counter Int = 1;

while (@Counter <= 10)
begin
  raiserror ('The counter value is %d', 0, 1, @Counter) with nowait;
  waitfor delay '00:00:01';
  set @Counter += 1;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for this example. It works fine from SQL Server Management Studio, but not from `SQLCMD`. It executes script in background for 10 seconds and when finished shows in output - all lines at the same time. `The counter value is 1 <...> The counter value is 10`

Comment: I don't believe sqlcmd processes the output in the same way. However MS also released an updated version called [Go-sqlcmd](https://github.com/microsoft/go-sqlcmd), I haven't used it but you could try it.

Comment: Thanks for this! Didn't know it exists. I'll give a try.

Answer (score 0):

You say

> I would like to use similar script to monitor backup and restore progress

Don't use this loop at all. Just use [the `STATS` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#stats---percentage-), where you can specify a percentage change to show an update. This is what all backup tools use to monitor progress.

```sql
BACKUP DATABASE
......
WITH STATS = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you.
In my case I have STATS option specified, but percentage is shown at the end of the backup, but not when backup operation is ongoing.
sqlcmd -SDB_HOST -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [MY_DB]
TO  DISK = 'C:\TEMP\MY_DB.bak'
WITH FORMAT,  STATS = 10;"

10 percent processed.
20 percent processed.
<...>
90 percent processed.
Processed 466152 pages for database 'MY_DB', file 'MY_DB_data' on file 1.
100 percent processed.

Comment: Could be sqlcmd doesn't display it until the command is finished. Try in SSMS it should work.

Comment: It seems you are right. Just found an answer stating "I believe SQLCMD was rewritten for 2012 in such a way that print statements and even raiserror messages issued during a run via SQLCMD never displayed until the entire job finished."

Comment: What happens if you use the `-j` option

Comment: Result is shown only at the very end with additional information:
`[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The counter value is 1
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The counter value is 2
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The counter value is 3
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The counter value is 4`

Answer (score 0):

One solution is mentioned in [How to show progress in a batch file using sqlcmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265434/how-to-show-progress-in-a-batch-file-using-sqlcmd). Other solution is to use Powershell.

```
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [scutility].[SqlCmdTestOutput]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @count INT = 50
    DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(8000)

    WHILE @count > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @msg = convert(VARCHAR(50), sysdatetime())

        RAISERROR (@msg,0,1) WITH NOWAIT

        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'

        SET @count -= 1
    END
END
```

And to call this procedure use Invoke-Sqlcmd.

`powershell.exe  -command "Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance '.' -Query '[scutility].[SqlCmdTestOutput]' -Database SCUTILITY -Verbose -QueryTimeout 0"`

More details here - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/222054/how-to-report-stats-on-restore-via-sqlcmd